# How I can navigate vba to the new tab after logging?

Tags: html, excel, vba

I login on some web page using vba excel code, and after login my IE page opens new tab and I need macro to change to this new tab and then continue this code there.

I have tried something like this but nothing is happening.

```
   objIE.navigate ""
   Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

 objIE.document.getElementById("sidebar").contentDocument.getElementById("Link0").Click
```

Comment: Look at prior answers which loop shell windows and find  right window by document.title or url. Or use selenium vba.

Comment: @QHarr thank you for your comment, but what do you mean loop shell windows ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?safe=strict&rlz=1C1GCEV_enGB851GB851&ei=7d7wXP2OGfKi1fAPytyT4AM&q=vba+find+ie+window&oq=vba+find+ie+window&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30l2j0i8i30.5786.6355..6602...0.0..0.169.552.0j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i8i7i30.cVAcXwCF3AA

Comment: @QHarr I found the right question and it works, thank you very much!